# arcpy.Project_management gives ERROR 000210?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, error-000210

I want to use [arcpy.Project_management](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/project.htm) to project my data.

I have....

```
arcpy.env.workspace = scratchGDB

fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fcList:
    print fc

>>> 
lease90
lease180
```

When I add the projection I get 'ExecuteError: ERROR 000210: Cannot create output'....

```
arcpy.env.workspace = scratchGDB

fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fcList:
    print fc
    WGS84aux = arcpy.SpatialReference(3857)
    arcpy.Project_management(fc, fc+ '_WGS84aux', WGS84aux)
```

Suggestions?

[image]

**UPDATE**:

I added a feature class to feature class and commented the projection out for test purposes -- the feature class to feature class worked. However, project still does not work.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = scratchGDB

fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fcList:
    print fc
    WGS84aux = arcpy.SpatialReference(3857)
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(fc, scratchGDB, fc + '_test')
    ##arcpy.Project_management(fc, fc+ '_WGS84aux', WGS84aux)
```

[image]

I've also projected manually and it works - I am so lost.

[image]

Comment: Do the input feature classes have a projection defined? Does the gdb have a projection set restricting it to a certain projection?

Comment: CurrentWorkspace should be supported with Project, but maybe be more explicit as a test? Add `import os` and change the output FC name to:  `os.path.join(scratchGDB, fc + '_WGS84aux')`

Comment: The input feature class projection is GCS_WGS_1984, and I need it in WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere. There is not a restriction on the scratchGDB.

Comment: @KHibma Tried - still does not work.

Comment: maybe change your spatial reference variable name to cs and try it...

Comment: Please always include error messages as text rather than pictures so that they can be available to future searches.

Comment: @KHibma I had to explicitly add a variable and assign it equal to os.path.join(scratchGDB, fc) for in the input in arcpy.Project_managment - Thanks for the lead.

Comment: Thats good news - take your "working" code and make an answer and accept it to close this out. (although I cant explain why that fixes it)

Comment: @KHibma Will do. I still don't understand why I would have to explicitly have to add a variable to os path join to the scratchGDB, if the arcpy.env.workspace = scratchGDB is set.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce this.

The test, which creates test data first, that I ran using ArcGIS 10.4.1 for Desktop on a local file geodatabase was:

```
import arcpy

if arcpy.Exists(r"C:\Temp\test.gdb"):
    arcpy.Delete_management(r"C:\Temp\test.gdb")  

arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(out_folder_path="C:/Temp",
                               out_name="test",
                               out_version="CURRENT")
arcpy.CreateFishnet_management(out_feature_class="C:/Temp/test.gdb/testFC",
                               origin_coord="0 0",
                               y_axis_coord="0 1",
                               cell_width="1", cell_height="1",
                               number_rows="1", number_columns="1",
                               corner_coord="", labels="NO_LABELS",
                               template="DEFAULT", geometry_type="POLYGON")
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(in_dataset="C:/Temp/test.gdb/testFC",
                                  coor_system="GEOGCS['GCS_WGS_1984',DATUM['D_WGS_1984',SPHEROID['WGS_1984',6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]]")

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\Temp\test.gdb"

fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print fcList
for fc in fcList:
    print fc
    WGS84aux = arcpy.SpatialReference(3857)
    arcpy.Project_management(fc, fc+ '_WGS84aux', WGS84aux)
print arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
```

The output was observed to be as expected:

```
>>> 
[u'testFC']
testFC
[u'testFC', u'testFC_WGS84aux']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to explicitly assign a variable to os.path.join(scratchGDB, fc). I don't understand why this would be needed if the environment workspace is set the the scratchGDB, but it worked.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = scratchGDB

fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
for fc in fcList:
    fcfull = os.path.join(scratchGDB, fc)
    WGS84aux = arcpy.SpatialReference(3857)
    projected = fcfull + 'WGSaux84'
    arcpy.Project_management(fcfull, projected, WGS84aux)
```